# How can I use Nested For Loop to create matrix

Tags: matrix

I use this code but it doesn't work.

```
ZZ = {
      {1, 2, 3, 4},
      {5, 6, 7, 8},
      {9, 10, 11, 12},
      {13, 14, 15, 16}
     } ;

ZZ // MatrixForm

K = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4, 4}];
K // MatrixForm

For[ i = 1, i = 4, i++,
  For [j = 1, j = 4, j++,
    K[[i, j, 1]] = ZZ[[i, 1]] ;   
    K[[i, j, 2]] = ZZ[[i, 2]] ;   
    K[[i, j, 3]] = ZZ[[i, 3]] ;  
    K[[i, j, 4]] = ZZ[[i, 4]] ;
   ]
];

K[[3, 2, 1]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please define "doesnt work".

Comment: I would use `Table`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html rather than your C-style code

Comment: I am new at Mathematica, may you show me a script?

Comment: Why not explain what you're actually trying to do with *Mathematica*?

Comment: @tolga08 You need to know the difference between `Set` and `Equal` (`=` and `==`).

Answer (score 5):

Needs `<=` to satisfy the condition.

```
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 4, j++,
  K[[i, j, 1]] = ZZ[[i, 1]];
  K[[i, j, 2]] = ZZ[[i, 2]];
  K[[i, j, 3]] = ZZ[[i, 3]];
  K[[i, j, 4]] = ZZ[[i, 4]];]]
```

Also  `K2 = Array[ZZ[[{#, #, #, #}]] &, 4]`

```
K == K2
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
Table[10 i + j, {i, 4}, {j, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

Please refer to:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html